# How to fix CA cert issues with Curl in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ssl, curl, certificates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I use curl, I get the following error:

`curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath:`

From what I gather from googling, the CAfile location it is looking for is not correct for Ubuntu (and it doesn't exist on my computer), `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is the proper location.

Most of the solutions involved setting the environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` to the proper location, or adding `cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` to the (newly created) `.curlrc` file in my home directory. I have tried both, and neither completely solve the issue.  curl is finding this location, but it still doesn't work, giving the error:

`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling curl in Ubuntu, and updating my CA certs with `$ sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` which updated the certs, but still didn't make error 60 go away.

I am not that knowledgeable about CA certs, and doubt I purposely added some self signed certificate in the past. Perhaps by accident, I don't know.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Is there a way to actually start fresh with all my certs? Or does anyone even know how I go about figuring out where this self signed certificate is, and then how to remove it?

PS: I don't want to use the -k (aka --insecure) flag. I want to get this working securely.

Answer (score 12):

After researching and working on this over the last couple days I got it to work, and the answer ended up being rather simple.

I needed to set `capath=/etc/ssl/certs/`in my `.curlrc` file.

This got curl working on the command line. To further get curl to work in R (where I first encountered the problem) I also needed to have `cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` in my `.curlrc` file as tried before, otherwise it continued to look for `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

I still have no idea why I was seeing the error about self-signed certificates.

Based on some other random findings I also downloaded a certificate from the Curl website with:

```
sudo wget https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

into the same `certs` directory. Having `cafile` pointed at this worked as well. In the end I put it back to `ca-certificates.crt` and it still works.

I don't understand exactly why this worked or what is going on, but it is resolved.

Answer (score 10):

**cafile** key does not work for me (curl 7.45.0) but cacert (from --cacert option) does.
My **.curlrc** file:

```
capath=/etc/ssl/certs/
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: this worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04!

Answer (score 2):

After researching for a few times I got it to work, and the answer ended up being rather a simple one.

Open terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and change working directory:

```
 cd /etc/ssl/certs/
```

Download pem file in the **certs** folder

```
 sudo wget https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

Now open the file `.curlrc`

```
nano ~/.curlrc
```

Add the below lines in the open file

```
capath=/etc/ssl/certs/
cacert=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Now save the file and do your things using curl command.

**N.B** Here I used nano editor, but you can use any editor.

Answer (score 0):

We faced same problem with one of our C++ programs in Ubuntu 14.04.5. The `.curlrc` method was not taking effect.

This was solved by downloading the `ca-certificates.crt` to `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and creating a symbolic link `ca-bundle.crt` under `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` directory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to bypass it:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just making a symbolic link `ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`